# Accurate Formula and One Old-Exam Questions?!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, contest-math

We get stuck in a problem on old-exam.

\begin{equation*}
A=\sqrt{x+ \frac {2}{x}} -\sqrt{x- \frac {2}{x}}~\text{and}~x>>1. 
\end{equation*}

For calculating $A$ which of the following option give a more accurate for primary formula ?

$ I) \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$ for $x>\sqrt{\frac{2}{u}}$

$ II) \frac{2}{x\sqrt{x}}$ for $x>\sqrt{\frac{2}{u}}$

$ III) \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$ for $x>\frac{2}{u}$

$ IV) \frac{2}{x\sqrt{x}}$ for $x>\frac{1}{u}$

> The important aspect of this question is that $U$ not defined. how can
>   describe it and say which of the option is true?

Answer (score 3):

The numerically stable formula for that expression is obtained via binomial formulas, 
$$
A=\sqrt{x+ \frac {2}{x}} -\sqrt{x- \frac {2}{x}}
=\frac{\left(x+ \frac {2}{x}\right) -\left(x- \frac {2}{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x+ \frac {2}{x}} + \sqrt{x- \frac {2}{x}}}
\\
=\frac{2}{x\sqrt{x}}·\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+ \frac {2}{x^2}} + \sqrt{1- \frac {2}{x^2}}}
$$
Now $$\sqrt{1+h}=1+\frac12 h-\frac18h^2+\frac1{16}h^3-\frac{5}{128}h^4+…$$ so that $$\sqrt{1+h}+\sqrt{1-h}=2\left(1-\frac18h^2-\frac{5}{128}h^4-…\right)$$ and
$$
A=\frac{2}{x\sqrt{x}}·\frac{1}{1-\frac18·\frac4{x^4}+O(x^{-8})}
$$
Thus whenever $\frac1{2x^4}<\frac{\mu}2$ or $x>\sqrt[4\,]{\frac1\mu}$ the value of $A$ is accurately represented by the first factor, which gives an asymptotically correct formula.

---

Here $\mu$ is the smallest positive number so that in the floating point type $1+\mu$ is different from $1$ is different from $1-\mu/2$. For the `double` type, $\mu=2^{-52}\simeq 2·10^{-16}$ is a little larger than $10^{-16}$, which means that already for $x>10^{4}$ the short formula is correct within the floating point precision.

---

Diagram comparing the absolute numerical and approximation errors:

[image: numerical and approximation errors]

and the relative errors (showing that $x>10^4$ is a reasonable bound) (note that the errors of the original expression had to be scaled down radically to even be visible)

[image: relative errors]

where $f(x)$ is the original expression for $A$, $g(x)$ the stabilized expression per the binomial formula and $h(x)$ the approximation by the first factor.

---

### Another approach

The original motivation for this selection of possibilities may be that for $x>\sqrt{\frac2\mu}$ the term $\frac2x$ is so small that it does not contribute any digits to the expressions $x\pm \frac2x$, i.e., $fl(x\pm \frac2x)=fl(x)$, where $fl$ denotes rounding to floating point precision. At that point $$fl(\sqrt{fl(x+2/x)})-fl(\sqrt{fl(x-2/x)})=0,$$ which obviously is not acceptable as numerical result.

So to get any kind of reasonable result, one needs a modified formula for larger $x$. The additional question one should ask is if an earlier use of the asymptotic expression would yield better precision than the original formula? To which the (empiric) answer is: Yes, already for $x>1000$ (surely, $x>500$  mostly) the asymptotic formula has a better error than the original formula.

[image: double logarithmic relative errors]

Theoretically, the relative floating point error of the original formula is $\sim \mu x^2$, the relative error of the asymptotic formula $\sim x^{-4}$, thus the cross-over point is at $\sqrt[6\,]{\frac1\mu}\simeq 4.7·10^2$, which coincides with the empirical results.

Comment: you means none of them is correct? or (4) ?

Comment: If anything, then II) comes close. But for $x=2·10^8>\sqrt{2/\mu}$ the original formula as floating point algorithm is meaningless, $2/x$ is too small against $x$ and gets swallowed in the addition/subtraction. Thus the floating point value of $A$ in the original form is $0$, while the modified form gives $(4/x)/(2\sqrt{x})=\sqrt{1/2}·10^{-12}$, as does the approximation formula. So yes, for the indicated boundaries in II) and IV) the approximation gives the same floating point result as an exact evaluation of $A$ rounded to floating point, but the boundaries are much too pessimistic.

Comment: Note that with $1/\mu=10^{16}$, $\sqrt{1/\mu}=10^8$ is the much smaller value. And $\sqrt[4\,]{1/\mu}=10^4$ is even smaller.

Comment: +1. but would you please your description in comment is more simpler? I and III is wrong. II and IV is true, but the boundaries is incorrect and the correct one Is  $ \sqrt \frac {1}{u}$ ?

Comment: there is a typo in your answer in another approach !!!

Comment: IV is useless (not even wrong), from $\sqrt{2/u}$ to $1/u$ you would get $0$ as numerical result. -- One can not say that the boundary in II is incorrect, it is at the point where one needs to do something with the original formula. But it is not a good boundary from the perspective of implementing such a function in real life. In total, it is not a good problem since the transformed formula is also good for very large $x$, there is no real need for the asymptotic expression.

Comment: so at final point 2 is better choice  but not good.

Comment: fl(sqrt(fl(x+2/x)))−fl(sqrt(fl(x−2/x))=0, I think is wrong !! please use mathJx.

Comment: what do you mean by "approximation by the first factor" ?

Comment: The asymptotic expression $2/(x\sqrt{x})$ which is the first factor in the transformed formula for $A$.

Comment: why you didn't correct the math expression in "another approach" part ?

Comment: my last question is what do u mean by " that in the floating point type 1+μ  is different from 1  is different from 1−μ/2 . "

Comment: I changed it, but obviously did not save it. -- The differences are between the next floating point numbers before and after $1$, that is $1+\mu=(1.00…001)_2$ and $1-mu/2=(0.111…111)_2$ with $53$ digits from the first to the last $1$. Usually while learning about floating point types, one gets the exercise to program iterations like `double x=1; int k=0; while(1+x!=1){x/=2; k++;} print(k)` and `float x=1; int k=0; while(x>0){x/=2; k++;} print(k)`.

Answer (score 0):

I) and III) can be dropped immediately for being "wrong".
The error in using $\sqrt{x\pm\frac 2x+\frac1{x^3}}=\sqrt x\pm\frac1{x\sqrt x}$ is fairly small, namely approximately $\frac1{x^2}$ times the derivative of the square root at $x\pm\frac2x\approx x$, i.e., $\approx \frac1{2x^2\sqrt x}$. Hence the total error from both summands is $\approx \frac1{x^2\sqrt x}$, and in fact the errors are more cancelling than adding up. Hence if an error of $u$ is acceptable, $x>\sqrt{\frac1u}$ is certainly sufficient.

Comment: is it possible make it clearer?

Comment: would you please inspect the options?